# LIKE a post on page wall

Tags: facebook, api

I have been searching all over but cannot find an answer:

With my app a page admin can publish a post to his page. I am now looking for a way to also allow users to LIKE the post via my app in such a way that the LIKE count for the post on the page actually increases.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Likes connection of the Post object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/#likes):

> You can like a Post by issuing a HTTP POST request to the
>   POST_ID/likes connection with the publish_stream permission

You'll need to ask for the `publish_stream` permissions from you users and then you can (JS example):

```
FB.api("POST_ID/likes", function(response) {
    console.log("Like response: ", response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can like a Post via the Graph API by making an HTTP POST request to graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes connection with an access token that has `publish_stream` permission. Read more about this here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/#likes